# Why does my Quicksort program not sort items correctly?

Tags: python, quicksort

My quicksort program is changing the order of the items in the list in the right direction, but it does not fully sort them.

```py
def quick_sort(arr, low, high):
    if (low < high):
        pi = pivot(arr, low, high)
        pivot(arr, low, pi-1)
        pivot(arr, pi+1, high)

def pivot(arr, low, high):
    i = ( low-1 )         
    pivot = arr[high]      

    for j in range(low , high): 

        if   arr[j] <= pivot: 

            i += 1
            arr[i],arr[j] = arr[j],arr[i] 


    arr[i+1], arr[high] = arr[high], arr[i+1] 
    return ( i + 1 ) 
print (numbers)
quick_sort(numbers, 0, len(numbers)-1)
print (numbers)
```

I expected the results to be correctly sorted instead of partially sorted.

ex. [-9859, -8554, -9846, -9558, -9153, -9483, -7946, -8255, -9743, -8330, -7632, -7513, -7125, 1756, -5176, -441, -3385, 896, -4748, 3811, 4285, -5883, -4342, 6275, 5753, 585, -2491, -243, -3590, -4377, 5986, -3393, -3727, 2976, -1532, -3924, 53, -2461, -5882, -1022, 2881, -3586, -3191, 6153, -4970, -5602, -5944, 5528, -3281, 1515, -680, -1975, -2472, -4371, -2574, -5248, -773, -271, -1967, 5079, 3040, -5871, 4825, 2810, -2301, 1371, 315, 2911, 2669, 2477, -3205, -2350, 2402, 5217, 6205, 2593, 4595, -4340, 6654, 7783, 9653, 8331, 8092, 6869, 7556, 9719, 8555, 9430, 8137, 9057, 8124, 7662, 6991, 6928, 7728, 7849, 7955, 7696, 7775]

Comment: Learning to debug by yourself is as important as (is integral part of) learning to program... Try adding `print` statements to follow what's going on an a smaller example...

Comment: Also try adding comments explaining explicitly the logic you are following, at every step, ask yourself if this logic makes sense, and double check that every single part of your code does precisely what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not looked in detail into your implementation of `pivot` (so there may be additional issues), but the top-level function `quick_sort` has one obvous problem. You're calling `pivot` three times from it, but you should instead be calling it only once, and recursively calling `quick_sort` the other two times.

Try:

```
def quick_sort(arr, low, high):
    if (low < high):
        pi = pivot(arr, low, high)
        quick_sort(arr, low, pi-1)
        quick_sort(arr, pi+1, high)
```

The recursion is important, because it sorts on successively smaller and smaller intervals. Your current code effectively sorts items into four buckets, but within those buckets, the values will be in a random order.